# SpringBeanFacesELResolver is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/el/ELResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im having problems with Docker Desktop when building an image, it must be incompatibility issues with versions of dependencies, im desperate idk what to do... how can i know the errors... it never says it clear.

This is my build.gradle (below my Dockerfile)

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.akkodis'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // JoinFaces para integrar JSF en Spring Boot
    implementation 'org.joinfaces:jsf-spring-boot-starter:4.1.1'

    // PrimeFaces
    implementation 'org.primefaces:primefaces:8.0'

    // Mojarra (una implementación de JSF)
    implementation 'org.joinfaces:mojarra-spring-boot-starter:4.1.1'

    // Omnifaces, útil para el desarrollo con JSF
    implementation 'org.joinfaces:omnifaces3-spring-boot-starter:4.1.1'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }


    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation 'javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

DOCKERFILE HERE

```
# 1. Actualiza la imagen base a JDK 11
FROM amazoncorretto:17 as build

# 2. Establece el directorio de trabajo en el contenedor
WORKDIR /app

# 3. Copia el proyecto Gradle en el contenedor
COPY . /app

# Asegúrate de que gradlew tenga permisos de ejecución
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew

# 4. Construye el proyecto usando Gradle Wrapper para generar el archivo WAR
RUN ./gradlew build

# 5. Utiliza Tomcat o cualquier otro contenedor de servlets compatible con archivos WAR para la imagen final
FROM tomcat:9-jdk17

# 6. Copia el archivo WAR generado a la carpeta de despliegues de Tomcat
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

# 7. Expone el puerto que tu aplicación utiliza (ajústalo según sea necesario)
EXPOSE 8080

# 8. Tomcat expone por defecto el puerto 8080, así que no es necesario especificarlo de nuevo.
# No es necesario definir un CMD porque la imagen base de Tomcat ya tiene uno por defecto que arranca el servidor.
```

And in Docker Desktop it says error:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Source Document: jar:file:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ejercicio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain/WEB-INF/lib/joinfaces-autoconfigure-4.1.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Class 'org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/el/ELResolver
```

im desperate what can i do...

I tried changing versions of things many times

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Error clearly says, you are missing dependency, Please check and add correct dependency, create build again.  Use correct version, example below:

implementation group: 'jakarta.el', name: 'jakarta.el-api', version: '6.0.0-RC1'

Comment: Your dependency config is a mess. You're mixing various javax* dependencies and jakarta* dependencies. This is not compatible. You need to make sure that you pick versions which *only* target legacy javax* **or** versions which *only* target modern jakarta*. And also try to not outsmart Spring Boot's transitive dependencies by redeclaring duplicate dependencies. Start as small as possible with *only* `spring-boot-starter-web` and carefully add remaining dependencies one by one whenever you actually **need** them.